# Como ingresar la fecha local en un campo mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla en mysql en la cual con un formulario agrego los registros y en ellos va un campo donde se inserta la fecha en que se realizo el nuevo ingreso.

```
<input name="fechaingreso" type="hidden" value="<?= gmdate('d-m-Y H:i:s', time()) ?>" readonly="readonly" size="20">
```

Funciona muy bien, pero me inserta la fecha del servidor y yo necesito que sea la hora local de mi ubicacion geografica.

Gracias por su valiosa colaboracion. Feliz dia.

Comment: el codigo completo, mis disculpas.<input name="fechaingreso" type="hidden" value="<?= gmdate('d-m-Y H:i:s', time()) ?>" readonly="readonly" size="20">

Comment: PHP funciona del lado del servidor, para tomar la fecha desde el cliente debes hacerlo con Javascript. Lee [Javascript Dates](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) para saber cómo usar el date del sistema

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu amable respuesta. Consultare lo que me sugieres. Hasta luego y feliz dia.